# How do I get the CSS selector of an element with Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have an element extracted from the DOM using JSOUP. I want to get the CSS selector of that element, so I can quickly find the equivalent elements on other pages with the same structure. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "other pages"? Each page has it's own structure. It would be pure coincidental luck if a page has the same class names etc. on it's HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it's possible, because multiple selectors could be valid for your element -- eg, the trivial `Selector.select("*",rootElement)` would match it.

It sounds like you don't want to use the same element-extraction code (that you initially used) for all subsequent documents?  If you're intent on using selectors, then perhaps try different ones until you find one that you're happy with (from either a readability or a performance perspective).